# Traffic shaping linux shell users on a per-user basis

Tags: tc

I have a debian 7 server with a number of shell users and I would like to limit upload and download rate on all interfaces (eth0, gre1, sit1) on a per user basis so each user has his own 75KB/s upload & download rate.

I have looked into tc but the solutions I found here and elsewhere did not seem like they would suit my needs, especially since they involved adding iptables rules for each user (100+)

Currently I have some rate limiting rules in place such as limiting pps and number of connections that seem to prevent outgoing DoS and flooding, but I know its not a cure all solution and would like to tighten things up a bit more.

When I tried to implement tc rules it seemed to limit the entire servers bandwidth and not each user like I wanted and I gave up.

Is there any pro's out there who can help?